# Why is the engine surging in my Craftsman lawn tractor?

Tags: small-engine, briggs-stratton

How can I stop my lawn tractor engine from surging at low throttle/RPM? I have an 18.5 hp Briggs and Stratton single cylinder. I have re-built the carburetor and adjusted the mixture screw.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was it surging before you rebuilt your carb (ie: was that the reason you rebuilt it)?

Comment: Yes and yes. Also, I observe that the hand throttle has a higher limit at the low end. Before I rebuilt my carburetor, I could idle it down to a stall position. Now I can't.

Comment: I assume there's not a wind-vane governor on it? If there is, the surging could be due to a weak spring on it. There's isn't one on my mower, so assume there isn't one on yours either. I just use the throttle adjustment  near the steering wheel. How bad is the surging? I mean is it within a couple hundred RPMs, or is it from near dead to 2000 RPMs? (Just throwing numbers out).

Comment: What did you replace when you rebuilt the carb?  Did you clean all of the components with carb cleaner?  I have experienced this on my generator.  A good clean of the jets with carb cleaner sorted it out.

Comment: It does have a windvane governor where the flap is inside the crankcase which turns a shaft coming out the side of the engine. When adjusting the hand throttle, it does not adjust the throttle plate on the carburetor. It adjusts the governor to increase or decrease engine speed. When surging the RPMs are changing few thousand RPMs, not to a near stall condition. Cleaned everything with carb cleaner when rebuilding it. Especially the needle valve. at time of rebuild I replaced (from the kit), The needle valve and all gaskets.

Comment: The governor rod (out of the side of the engine crankcase) can be seen to oscillate at low throttle/RPM point.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by XLrick, on B&S engines the throttle cable pulls on a spring connected to the governor flap which is linked to the throttle plate.
Now *if the engine wants to die at low speeds*,  in the case where you throttle down to idle the RPMs fall off *too far* and the governor then jerks the throttle open and the engine takes off, and the governor closes the throttle and the engine slows down, wants to die, and the governor catches it by jerking the throttle open. Surge-surge-surge.

So *surging at low speeds* is an indication that the carb's low-speed jet/circuit is blocked or misadjusted in such a way that prevents the engine from getting enough fuel at idle.

To demonstrate this to yourself it is possible while the engine is running to carefully reach down to the linkage and work the throttle by hand in such a way that the governor flap can't pull on the throttle. then what you do is try to gradually close the throttle by hand and you'll probably discover that below a certain critical point (where the low-speed circuit is supposed to take over) the engine dies altogether and will not idle.

Then you take the carb apart and specifically go to work on the low speed circuit!